# scala count letter pairs in word

Tags: scala

I'm new to learning Scala and would appreciate any thoughts on an idiomatic way to do the following. I want to count occurrences of sequential letter pairs in a word.

For example, for the word "home", the output might be `Map("ho"->1,"om"->1,"me"->1)`. And for 'lulu', the result would be `Map("lu"->2, "ul"->1 )`.

So performing a simple single-letter count might be done as

```
"abracadabra".map(s => s).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
```

But I'm stumped as to how to add-in the two-letter component of this problem. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.sliding` :

```
scala> "abracadabra".sliding(2).toList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = 
        Map(br -> 2, ca -> 1, ab -> 2, ra -> 2, ac -> 1, da -> 1, ad -> 1)

scala> "lulu".sliding(2).toList.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(ul -> 1, lu -> 2)
```

From the docs :

> Sliding : Groups elements in fixed size blocks by passing a "sliding window" over them

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sliding(2)`:

```
"abracadabra".sliding(2).toVector.map(s => s).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.length)
// Map(br -> 2, ca -> 1, ab -> 2, ra -> 2, ac -> 1, da -> 1, ad -> 1)
```